# Activated Router nested children

Tags: angular, routes

I did search about this but i didnt find any concrete answer.

Is there a way to access all nested childrenroutes of an Activated Route, for example:

The main route have a children route1, the route1 have a children route2, the route2 have a children route3 and this way until we have no more childrenRoute.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can access your activated root data with firstChild and you're ganna get your children routes:

```
constructor(route: ActivatedRoute) {
  route.url.subscribe(() => {
    console.log(route.snapshot.firstChild.data);
   });
}
```

Then you can add some check conditions if you have a result or not. Don't forget to subscribe in case you change your route inside your current component.

Comment: This returns me just the child routes of the curren activated route.

Comment: So I guess I misunderstood your question... What do you want to achieve exactly ? To get all your routes and subroutes of your whole application ? Or to get all the children of the currently activated route ?